# How to use axios "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to send an array of Ints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send the data `[8, 0]` to a server, but the server isn't receiving it correctly.

```
axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/api/v1/project/delete",
  params: {
    project_id_json: [8, 0]
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  data: bodyFormData
})
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
```

Comment: You're not sending JSON, you're sending an array of Ints... is this intentional?

Comment: Yes .I want send array

Answer (score 0):

As `string` should works
    params:  { project_id_json: "[8,0]" }

Comment: Not yet.but I test in postman form-data project_id_json = [8] it success

Answer (score 0):

Use req.query on server side to fetch the data. You will find the object sent as params there.